# DrawLine: Top and Left are incorrect

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, picturebox

I have a custom control which consists of a Panel and a smaller pictureBox. When I DrawLine from Left,Top to Right,Bottom in the pictureBox, the starting point does not start in the corner of the pictureBox, and is offset +x and +y. If I expand the pictureBox to take up the entire size of the Panel, it lines up correctly. What's going on?

The pictureBox is Anchored to Top, Bottom, Left, and Right. No Docking.

```
private void pictureBoxPlot_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightGray,
        pictureBoxPlot.Left, pictureBoxPlot.Top,
        pictureBoxPlot.Right, pictureBoxPlot.Bottom);

    pictureBoxPlot.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: It begs the question why you are using an *extra* control when you can also use the panel's Paint event.  Beyond the control just having an offset in the panel from having a non-zero Location, PictureBox also alters the e.Graphics object to implement the SizeMode property.  Surely it is the Location property here.  Using PictureBox is a *really* expensive way to get the DoubleBuffered property set to true.

Comment: Since I was drawing within the parent's region (and beyond) I was hosing other controls and thought that OnPaint() would update them... first time writing drawing code for me... Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controls have their own coordinate system starting at (0, 0), so draw it like that:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightGray,
    0, 0, pictureBoxPlot.ClientSize.Width, pictureBoxPlit.ClientSize.Height);
```

The `pictureBoxPlot.Invalidate()` should be removed since that would cause it to recursively call itself.  Also, the `base.OnPaint(e)` looks out of place since you didn't override the paint method.

Comment: I was beating my head against the wall for a few hours! I removed the OnPaint() and Invalidate(). Works as expected - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the coordinates are relative to the picture box.  If you want upper left, and a full line, use something like:  `0, 0, pictureBoxPlot.height, pictureBoxPlot.Width`

Answer (score 1):

Draw is relative to your canvas. You are are attempting to draw where the actual location of the box resides on the form. Use `PictureBoxPlot.ClientSize`

Comment: This is probably why I noticed other controls getting hosed. Thanks!